# Problem in using cURL and REST API of TFS to install extension

Tags: curl, tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

I am trying to use the REST API of TFS 2018 to install an extension on our server with the help of cURL. This process must be repeated everyday, and that's why I'd like to run it using a command with cURL.

So far I figured out how to get a list of all the installed extensions on the server with the following command. This tells me the connection and the authentication work well.

```
curl -u {username}:{PAT} -d "" -X GET http://{instance}/{collection}/_apis/extensionmanagement/installedextensions?api-version=4.1-preview.1
```

To install the extension I have read this info from microsoft doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/extensionmanagement/installed%20extensions/install%20extension%20by%20name?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1

I try formulate a command to install an extension I found here:https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks.

The command is:

```
curl -u {username}:{PAT} -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://{instance}/{collection}/_apis/extensionmanagement/installedextensionsbyname/benjhuser/tfs-extensions-build-tasks/3.0.14?api-version=4.1-preview.1
```

I think the publisher, id and version of the extension should be correct, because I took them from this release document: https://github.com/huserben/TfsExtensions/blob/master/BuildTasks/vss-extension.json.

The response says the extension doesn't exist. This is confusing. Could someone please give me some hints, what the problem can be? Thank you in advance.

```
{
  "$id": "1",
  "innerException": null,
  "message": "The requested extension 'benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks' doesn't exist.",
  "typeName": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Gallery.WebApi.ExtensionDoesNotExistException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Gallery.WebApi",
  "typeKey": "ExtensionDoesNotExistException",
  "errorCode": 0,
  "eventId": 3000
}
```

Comment: Hi friend, does the answer below resolved your question? If my reply helped or gave a right direction. Appreciate for [marking it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) which will also help others in the community.

Comment: @WalterQian-MSFT I tried the command without speicfying the version, but it still throw back the same error.

Comment: Please try to use installedextensionsbyname instead of installedextensions in your command. Please also check the screenshot of result in my answer.

Comment: Hi friend, please use another GET API first before installing the extensions. I updated my   answer. Feel free to contact me if you have any confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Install Extension By Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/extensionmanagement/installed%20extensions/install%20extension%20by%20name?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1) Rest API is used to Install pre-installed extensions. You need to add the extensions locally. Please refer to the document about [Install extensions for on-premises servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/marketplace/get-tfs-extensions?view=tfs-2018).

Please try the following steps:

1.Open the developer tool(F12) of the browser and click install button. You can find the publisher name and extension name in the URL.[image]
2.Check the network tab in the developer tool(F12). You can find a REST API like

`GET http://{instance}/{collection}/_gallery/items?itemName={publisher name}.{extension name}&install=true&installContext={Some context}`.

The installContext will not change, you only need to change the publisher name and extension name here every time you install a new extension:
[image]
3.Now, you can find this extension in the local extensions.
[image]

After this, you can use the Install Extension By Name API to Install Extensions.

**Steps summery**:

1.`curl -u {username}:{PAT} -X GET http://{instance}/{collection}/_gallery/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks&install=true&installContext={installContext}`

2.`curl -u {username}:{PAT} -d "" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://{instance}/{collection}/_apis/extensionmanagement/installedextensionsbyname/benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks?api-version=4.1-preview.1`

Here is my result:
[image]

In addition, Azure DevOps Services can use Install Extension By Name API directly.

Comment: OK, I see. I don't know much about web app development, but if the api installedextensionsbyname is only useful in installing an extension which was previously installed on the server, then that beats my purpose. Is there a way to install the extension for the first time using the API. Anyway thank you so much for looking into it.

Comment: Please use the GET API in my answer first when you install extensions. Then, you can find them in local extensions. You just need to get the installContext at the first time.  You can only use the api installedextensionsbyname to install the extensions that exist in local extensions.

Comment: I tried your get command. The returned error says, the command "install" and "installContext" is not written correctly or can't be found.

Comment: The output in the html format shows "A public action method 'items' was not found on controller 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Gallery.Web.GalleryController'."

Comment: Would you share your get command with me for further troubleshooting if you still have this issue?

Comment: This is the command I used, the url is directly copied from the "Request URL" of the developer console of browser:

curl -u {user}:{token} -X GET http://tfs:8080/tfs/_gallery/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks&install=true&installContext=eyJpdGVtTmFtZSI6ImJlbmpodXNlci50ZnMtZXh0ZW5zaW9ucy1idWlsZC10YXNrcyIsIml0ZW1VcmwiOiJodHRwczovL21hcmtldHBsYWNlLnZpc3VhbHN0dWRpby5jb20vaXRlbXM%252faXRlbU5hbWU9YmVuamh1c2VyLnRmcy1leHRlbnNpb25zLWJ1aWxkLXRhc2tzIiwiY29sbGVjdGlvbklkIjoiMjE4MmExN2MtNWZhZS00N2Y2LWExODctYmNkYmUzYmM0MTUxIn0%253d

Comment: Please try the following workarounds:1.Add double quotes around the request URL:curl -u {user}:{token} -X GET "URL" 2.Copy the URL and paste it to the browser. I look forward to your reply.

Comment: I just tried out the 2 options:
1. After adding the quotation marks, the respose directed to an output file is a html file, but obviously the extension is not installed at background.
2. When I paste the URL to browser and enter, it goes to the page where I am required to confirm the installation of the extension.

Comment: The extension will be added to the local extensions. Now,you can use the Install Extension By Name Rest API to install this extension.

Comment: This time it works! Thank you so much for your effort in helping me solving the problem!